# ADF copy activity failed while extracting data from DB2- Issue found for few records having special characters

Tags: azure, db2, azure-data-factory

I am doing a full extract from a table ABC. In copy activity, I have given a query as

`select * from ABC`
whereas I am facing issue for few rows (It has special characters - Japanese and Korean)

**Error code** 2200

**Failure type** User configuration issue

**Details** Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=DB2DriverRunFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error thrown from driver. Sql code: '-343',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Db2Connector,''Type=Microsoft.HostIntegration.DrdaClient.DrdaException,Message=HISMPCB0001 In BasePrimitiveConverter an exception has occurred. Exception description: Output buffer is smaller than required size 12 SQLSTATE=HY000 SQLCODE=-343,Source=Microsoft.HostIntegration.Drda.Requester,'

The character which is causing the issue is '轎ᆃ         '

Comment: what is the codepage of your DB2 database ?

Answer (score 0):

In the error description, it states that there is BasePrimitiveConverter exception that has occurred. The exception description indicates that the output buffer is smaller than the required size. So, please try converting the column to an acceptable type like graphic in db2. Refer to the following link to understand more.

https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/488983-storing-some-japanese-data

Referring to these links, I understand that this error might be due to the datatype of source column, or the encoding used. Try working with different encoding options available in your source dataset. Here is a similar problem with a different source but a similar problem of not being able to retrieve special characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/467456/failure-happened-source-side-in-copy-activity-for.html

Comment: For few tables, Casting to DBCLOB worked. But for some special characters, We still had issues and not able to extract using ADF. Encoding is also not working.